# Quotient group and adjoint matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, quotient-spaces

The exercise 1211 in "Problems and Solutions in Mathematics" by Ta-Tsien:

*Let $M$ be an $n \times n$ matrix of integers. Suppose that $M$ is invertible when viewed as a matrix of rational numbers.
Show that $\mathbb{Z} / M \mathbb{Z}^n$ is finite.*

The proposed answer is:

*It is obvious from the facts that the map: $g:\mathbb{Z}^n/ M \mathbb{Z}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^n / |M| \mathbb{Z}^n$, $\delta(\overline{X}) = \overline{M^*X}$ is injective, and the fact that $|\mathbb{Z}^n / |M| \mathbb{Z}^n| = (|\det M|)^n$.*

$|M|$ is the determinant of $M$ and $M^*$ is the adjoint of $M$.

I think there is a typo and $\delta$ and $g$ designate the same function. Can someone details why this function is injective, and why $|\mathbb{Z}^n / |M| \mathbb{Z}^n| = (|\det M|)^n$ ?

Comment: Does $\overline X$ denote the equivalence class of $X$?

Comment: I think you're right about the typo

Comment: By adjoint do you mean the transpose, or do you mean the [classical adjoint (AKA adjugate)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix)?

Comment: I copied the question directly, I do not have much more clues :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $k$ be any positive integer. Is it obvious for you that $\Bbb{Z}^n/k\Bbb{Z}^n$ is the same as $(\Bbb{Z}/k\Bbb{Z})^n$? If yes, then $|\Bbb{Z}^n/k\Bbb{Z}^n|=k^n$, so the last equality applies with $k=|M|$ (the symbol $|M|$ usually denotes the determinant of $M$).

Now, denote by $k=\det M$. It is well known that $M^*M=MM^*=kI$, where $I$ denotes the identity matrix. In particular this implies that $M^*M\Bbb{Z}^n=k\Bbb{Z}^n$.

Consider the composition of the maps
$$\Bbb{Z}^n \longrightarrow \Bbb{Z}^n \longrightarrow \Bbb{Z}^n/k\Bbb{Z}^n$$
where the first map is multiplication by $M^*$, the second is the canonical projection.  Clearly the kernel of this map is
$$\{ v \in \Bbb{Z}^n: M^*v \in k\Bbb{Z}^n\} = \{ v \in \Bbb{Z}^n: M^*v \in M^*M\Bbb{Z}^n\} = M\Bbb{Z}^n$$
where the second inequality follows from the fact that $M^*$ has rank $n$. Moreover this map is surjective.

So by the first isomorphism theorem
$$\Bbb{Z}^n/M\Bbb{Z}^n \cong \Bbb{Z}^n/k\Bbb{Z}^n$$
and actually the isomorphism is exactly the map $g$ (or $\delta$).

Comment: Thank you for this very clear explanation.